# Testflight of IOS takes a very long time to add a build

Tags: ios, testflight

I am currently testing an app via testflight. When adding "external testers" it is required to add a build.

When I tried to choose a build and hit "next" button, It really took a long time and it keeps spinning, regardless of Chrome or Safari. It is still spinning now for up to 20mins.

See below, do anyone has any similar problems?

[image: Takes a long time to select a build for beta review]

Answer (score 0):

Open your browsers developer/inspector tools and look at the console tab to see if any errors are being thrown. This may give you some tips as to what may be going wrong (if anything).